# deseriaize using json in .net (multiple types)

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am new to **.net**. Maybe this is a basic question. I tried many ways by looking at similar questions in stackoverflow. But so far no luck. The actual problem is,
I have the below string and I want to deserialize using jsonconvert.

`{"Type1":[{"id":0,"x":1,"y":3,"frame":0,"speed":20},{"id":9,"x":1,"y":3,"frame":0,"speed":20}],"Type2":[]}`

the way I am deserializing it as below

`var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootCommands>(body);`

I have used the tool http://json2csharp.com/ to have classes generated from the json string.

```
public class Type1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int frame { get; set; }
    public int speed { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Type1> Type1 { get; set; }
    public List<object> Type2 { get; set; }
}
```

But still I get the following execption when I try to print the constrcuted object data `temp.Type1.Count`

`Inside exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Looking forward to your response

Comment: In your question, you are deserializing to `RootCommands`, but your class is defined as `RootObject`.  Is this a typo, or is `RootCommands` a different class?  If I deserialize to `RootObject`, it works fine:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEARFx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your 'body'-object looks like. But I tested it with this code and it seems to work fine:

```
string body = @"{ 'Type1':[{'id':0,'x':1,'y':3,'frame':0,'speed':20},{'id':9,'x':1,'y':3,'frame':0,'speed':20}],'Type2':[]}";
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(body);
```